# how to install amazon jdk on centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos7, redhat, rpm, corretto

I am trying to install the rpm package `java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64.rpm` on `centos 7 OS`.

I have downloaded the `rpm java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64.rpm` from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html

When trying to install using the command

`rpm -ivh java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64.rpm`

I get the following error:

```
warning: java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID c87f5b1a: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2 is needed by java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1:1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64
    libX11.so.6()(64bit) is needed by java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1:1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64
    libawt.so()(64bit) is needed by java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1:1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64
    libawt_xawt.so()(64bit) is needed by java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1:1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64
    libawt_xawt.so(SUNWprivate_1.1)(64bit) is needed by java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1:1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64
    libjava.so()(64bit) is needed by java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1:1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64
    libjvm.so()(64bit) is needed by java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1:1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64
```

Any idea how to download the rpm's that are required by  `java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64.rpm` ? I tried with yumdownloader but it didn't work.

```
yumdownloader --destdir=. --resolve java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: ftp.heanet.ie
 * extras: ftp.heanet.ie
 * updates: ftp.heanet.ie
No Match for argument java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64.rpm
Nothing to download
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two packages, one providing the JDK and one providing the JRE. If you want the JDK, you'll also need to install the JRE.

1. Download both RPMs from [Amazon Corretto's downloads page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html).
2. Install both simultaneously using [yum localinstall](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-yum-useful-commands):

   ```
   sudo yum localinstall -y java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto*.rpm
   ```

Comment: basically i want to download the rpms requred for java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64.rpm for offline usage.                                               I know yum install will work . but wants to download all rpms for the java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_192.b12-1.amzn2.x86_64.rpm on to a file system and use offline.

Comment: so using yumlocalinstall we can identify which rpms are required for amazon corretto rpms . then we can downloand those rpms using yumdownloader command , and dowonloade them offline then use rpm -vih to install all the rpms .. care must be take to resolve dependencies as rpm command is poor in handling dependences unlike yum